# Erro do retorno da expressão do tipo UITableViewCell no swift

Tags: swift

```
class OcorrenciaVinculadaCell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var tipoOcorrencia: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var descricao: UITextField!

}

class OcorrenciaVinculadasViewController: UITableViewController {

    var id:Int = 0;
    var schedulingId = 0;

    var ocorrencias:Array<Ocorrencia> = [];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.schedulingId = Util.schedullingId;

        OcorrenciaHttp.GetOcorrencia(
            success: {
                (ocorrencias) in
                self.ocorrencias = ocorrencias;
                self.tableView.reloadData();
            }
            ,fail: { (error) in
                print("Failure: \(error.localizedDescription)");
            }
        );
    }

    @IBAction func createOcorrenciaButton(_ sender: Any) {
        Util.schedullingId = schedulingId;
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return ocorrencias.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt
    indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell", for: indexPath) as! OcorrenciaViewCell

        let ocorrencia = ocorrencias[indexPath.row]

        cell.tipoOcorrencia.text = Util.GetText(text:ocorrencia.tipoOcorrencia?.Name) as? String;
        cell.descricao.text = Util.GetText(text: ocorrencia.descricao) as? String;

        return cell
    }
```

No retorno fica dando o erro:

> ```
> Cannot convert return expression of type 'OcorrenciaViewCell' to return type 'UITableViewCell'
> ```

Comment: isso está ocorrendo porque a função `tableView` espera que seja retornado um objeto do tipo `UITableViewCell` porém você está retornando `cell` que é um objeto do tipo `OcorrenciaViewCell`: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell", for: indexPath) as! OcorrenciaViewCell`. Você teria que converter `cell` em `UITableViewCell` só que na sua pergunta não mostra a declaração de `OcorrenciaViewCell` para saber se é possível ou se teria que criar um método de conversão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no

```
 override func viewDidLoad() { ...
```

adicione:

```
self.tableview.register(OcorrenciaViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"itemCell")
```

Confira na célula se voce colocou o identifier como `"itemCell"`

aproveitando, sempre chame o super em

```
override func viewDidLoad() { 
   super.viewDidLoad()
```